# Cannot list image tags into Jenkins active choices dropdown

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ecr

I use this script to display dropdown values from AWS Ecr:

```
def profile = "ecr"
def region = "us-east-1"
def cmd_output = "aws ecr describe-repositories --profile $profile --region $region --output yaml".execute()
def awk_cmd_output = cmd_output | ['awk', '/repositoryName:/ {print $2}'].execute()
def repo_names = awk_cmd_output.text.tokenize().reverse()
return repo_names
```

When I run the command into linux shell I get:

```
root@test:~# aws ecr describe-repositories --profile ecr  --region us-east-1
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "repositoryArn": "arn23522033165aws:ecr:us-east-1:73522033165:repository/test",
            "registryId": "23522033165",
            "repositoryName": "test",
            "repositoryUri": "23522033165.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test",
            "createdAt": "2023-09-07T22:30:50+00:00",
            "imageTagMutability": "MUTABLE",
            "imageScanningConfiguration": {
                "scanOnPush": false
            },
            "encryptionConfiguration": {
                "encryptionType": "AES256"
            }
        },
        {
            "repositoryArn": "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:23522033165:repository/test",
            "registryId": "23522033165",
            "repositoryName": "test-2",
            "repositoryUri": "23522033165.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test",
            "createdAt": "2023-09-09T19:54:04+00:00",
            "imageTagMutability": "MUTABLE",
            "imageScanningConfiguration": {
                "scanOnPush": false
            },
            "encryptionConfiguration": {
                "encryptionType": "AES256"
            }
        },
.....
}
```

Above configuration was working file. But after changing aws credentials using `aws configure` the listing is not working. I added api user as IAM user with a group into security settings:

[image]

But still I can't list images versions from a registry.
Do you know how I can fix this issue?

EDIT: I run the script this way:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should provide AWS creds in the Jenkinsfile.
To do so you need to add aws creds to jenkins and call them in the Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  options {
     withAWS(credentials: 'AWS_CREDENTIALS_ID', region: 'YOUR_REGION')
  }
```

Use withAWS wrapper in separate stage

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('hello AWS') {
      steps {
        withAWS(credentials: 'aws-credentials', region: 'your_region') {
          s3Upload acl: 'Private', bucket: 'bucket_name', file: 'hello.txt'
        }
```

Call aws creds as regular creds, just ignore WARNING in job output

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'master'
  }
  environment {
     ANY_TEXT_HERE = credentials('AWS_CREDENTIALS_ID_HERE')
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure? After Jenkins installation I did `aws configure` and set api keys. It should be be able to make api calls to aws ecr without the need of credentials.

Comment: Yes I am. Did you set aws creds on your host for the jenkins user?

Comment: Yes I set it using just `aws configure`.

Comment: But I run the groovy script separately from `pipileine{......}` section.

Comment: Try to list all env vars in your script jus t to check aws creds are available.

Comment: Can you show me how, please?

Comment: Just to clarify something. I updated the post with picture how I run the script.

Comment: I can't tell you how to list envs in groovy, but you can use shell in build step with 'printenv' command